# Running Heroku rake db:migrate on Heroku not migrating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

so when I run heroku rake db:migrate, after pushing my latest code Heroku doesn't alter the tables. However, when I try on my pc(where I also use Postgresql) and run rake db:migrate, it migrates the database and adds the necessary tables and fields to existing tables.

However, from heroku, I don't get any errors, this is the response I get.

```
 SQL (2.4ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'flow_elements'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.2ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"flows"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.7ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"flows"'::regclass

  SQL (2.7ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'flows'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.3ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"images"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.3ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"images"'::regclass

  SQL (2.3ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'images'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.2ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"login_histories"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.8ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"login_histories"'::regclass

  SQL (2.7ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'login_histories'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.1ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"projects"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.2ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"projects"'::regclass

  SQL (2.6ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'projects'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.3ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"projects_users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.5ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"projects_users"'::regclass

  SQL (2.4ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'projects_users'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (2.2ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"questions"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.2ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"questions"'::regclass

  SQL (2.4ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'questions'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  Columns for index questions_fts_idx on questions (1.8ms)   SELECT a.attnum, a.
attname
 FROM pg_attribute a
 WHERE a.attrelid = 48972
 AND a.attnum IN (0)

  SQL (2.1ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"screens"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (4.3ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"screens"'::regclass

  SQL (2.4ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'screens'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  SQL (3.0ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,
 a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  PK and serial sequence (3.6ms)   SELECT attr.attname, seq.relname
 FROM pg_class seq,
 pg_attribute attr,
 pg_depend dep,
 pg_namespace name,
 pg_constraint cons
 WHERE seq.oid = dep.objid
 AND seq.relkind = 'S'
 AND attr.attrelid = dep.refobjid
 AND attr.attnum = dep.refobjsubid
 AND attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid
 AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
 AND cons.contype = 'p'
 AND dep.refobjid = '"users"'::regclass

  SQL (2.4ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index d
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indexrelid = i.oid
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.oid = d.indrelid
 AND t.relname = 'users'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"'
,'public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname
```

**Any ideas ?**

Comment: Is that output from the app log? It just looks like Rails is introspecting the tables. First I'd make sure that the db isn't already migrated. Did you restart your rails app after the migration? It's possible that Rails is holding onto the old schema if the app is running in production mode.

Another possibility is a bad entry in schema_information. The easiest way I've found to check this sort of thing is to use taps to pull the prod db down to a local database. You can also issue SQL commands against the ActiveRecord::Base.connection object to check the prod db directly.

Comment: Hey, so the problem was(and this is pretty retarded that I didnt think of this before) I didn't restart the servers. Running heroku restart solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to restart the heroku servers using "heroku restart".